# Drives not getting associated

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, windows-explorer, file-association

When I click on my computer I can see a list of drives etc. But when I click on them I get the "Open With" dialog box. I've tried the drive association fix mentioned [here](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/file_assoc.htm). It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a random fix, but it worked wonders for a colleague who had the exact same problem:

1. Click **Start**
2. Click **Run**
3. Type **cmd** and click **OK** to bring up the command prompt
4. Type **attrib -r -s -h c:\autorun.inf** and press **Enter**
5. Type **del c:\autorun.inf** and press **Enter**

If it works, repeat steps 4-5 for each drive substituting c: for d: or e: or whatever other drives you have.

If not, the other fix which I have seen used for problems similar to this is:

1. Click **Start**
2. Click **Run**
3. Type **regsvr32 /i shell32.dll** and click **OK** twice

Comment: does ur first solution require a restart or anything?

Comment: The first fix is immediate whereas a restart would be a good idea for the second fix, just to make sure.

Comment: Ur first fix wasn't immediate. I think the 2nd fix worked somehow. Any idea wht tht does?

Comment: It just re-registers the DLL that contains information about the Windows interface.  Think of the above command as a little reset button.  Some more background info here: http://www.pcworld.com/article/126116/windows_tips_fix_windows_glitches_by_reregistering_your_dlls.html

Answer (score 0):

Start Registry Editor. (start -> Run... -> regedit)

navigate to:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell
```

Set (default) to "none" (without ")

Click OK.

Quit Registry Editor.

edit: If this problem is also related to folders, then start Registry Editor. (start -> Run... -> regedit)

navigate to:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell]
```

Set (default) to "none" (without ")

Click OK.

Quit Registry Editor.

Comment: The drive association fix mentioned in the question already does this.

Comment: well, if the {default} key is set to NONE, then doubleclick will just OPEN the drives and not perform ANY other action. if the problem persists then you might be in for a thorough malware check and/or system restore.